# Separating a Drupal module logic and UI

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6, drupal-modules

I wrote a D6 module which provide user with the ability to communicate, config params and test a 3rdparty API service.
The module works as intended  but I want to separate the communicator class and bundle it as foo module. Then pack the rest (admin page) as the foo-ui module. Just like views and views-ui.
I have no idea about what's the best-practices / design patterns to do so. Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I know, there is no specific pattern, but there's always a question:

> *-- Why should I separate my module's logic and UI into multiple modules? Is that really needed?*
>
> It's needed, only if you have developed a module which might accept different UIs just like [views](http://drupal.org/project/views) and [simple views](http://drupal.org/project/simpleviews). IMO there is no other reason to do so.

Ok, assuming that our module needs the `_ui` thing. Here I try to separate the core functionality of a module and its configuration UI as an example. Take a look at [Unfuddle API module](http://drupal.org/project/unfuddle_api), it's a pretty tiny and simple module which fits our case. Here is the `$ tree ./unfuddle_api`:

```
unfuddle_api/
|-- LICENSE.txt
|-- README.txt
|-- unfuddle_api.classes.inc
|-- unfuddle_api.info
|-- unfuddle_api.install
|-- unfuddle_api.module

0 directories, 6 files
```

Read its code! The `unfuddle_api.install` is installing no schema but implementing the `hook_uninstall()` to delete a few variables using `variable_del()` on module uninstall. These variables are actually the API connection parameters which will be set in admin page of the module, you might have a few of them in your module, too.
*IMO this is a part to be migrated to `unfuddle_api_ui` module.*

The file `unfuddle_api.classes.inc` is the API wrapper class for [unfuddle](http://unfuddle.com), it's somehow 3rdparty code wrapped in a class which will be used to instantiate an object.
*IMO this should be remained in the core module. But for the sake of design we have to change the constructor method by removing `variable_get()` calls and setting passed parameters straight to class properties. We'll add them later in `.module` file.*

The file `unfuddle_api.module` contains the main module code, An implementation of `hook_perm()` plus one for `hook_menu()` to create the admin page and a helper function named `unfuddle_api_create()` which is somehow a [Factory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) helper to create an object from `Unfuddle` class coded in `unfuddle_api.classes.inc`.
*IMO both hook implementations should be ported to the `_ui` module. Also the removed `variable_get()` part of the `unfuddle_api.classes.inc` discussed above, should be added here in the `unfuddle_api_create()` function*.

So, As an outline: We have a `unfuddle_api` module which acts as a wrapper for the `Unfuddle` API class. It provide us all the functionality but no configuration UI. All the configs should be set through the `unfuddle_api_create()` module in code.
Also we got a `unfuddle_api_ui` module which depends on `unfuddle_api` module and if enabled will provide us with the core module configuration in UI.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

Also it is usefull for modules that does not use UI offten. Disabling UI saves some resources.
I suggest you to check imagecache module as an example. http://drupal.org/project/imagecache

Answer (score 1):

There is no easy answer. You need to enforce the separation of functionality from the User interface **yourself**. So you need to put all the APIs of your program in one module and the user interface in another. Write test cases for your API -- using the [simpletest](http://drupal.org/project/simpletest) module. By writing test cases you are becoming the "consumer" of your APIs. In fact, you can delay the implementation of your UI long enough that you are sure that you have the correct set of functions/classes in the module responsible for "core" functionality.

Also you should explore the [CTools](http://drupal.org/project/ctools) module. It gives some useful tools like being able to make exportables and so on.

Drupal does not have a wealth of literature in book form like Java or C# for instance. But PHP does. Check out books on design patterns in PHP. Though I haven't read it, "PHP in action" by Manning seems to have a lot of stuff on precisely the things you're asking.

Another way to do such things is to see how others have done it. The imagecache module is small enough and it separates the UI from functionality (there is a separate Imagecache UI module you need to enable). Why not actually explore the source code of imagecache? [Views is 1 MB+ of source code so its probably not a good idea to explore that just yet :-)]

Comment: thank you, I've wrote test cases already for the API and its wrapper which are the core functionality of the module. I thought that there is a specific pattern to separate logic and ui for Drupal modules. thank you again.

Comment: +1 on the answer and +1 on "PHP in Action" by Manning. I also suggest PHP Objects, Patterns, and Practice, Second Edition by Zandra